# Android and UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a peculiar issue with Android and a JNI library that I am using. The JNI library is named libBase.so and is properly included in the APK. I am able to do System.loadLibrary("Base") and the library gets loaded and can be used without any problems.

Consider the following code snippets:

```
/* NativeObject.java */
public class NativeObject
{
    /* ... */
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("Base");
    }
}

/* ObjectUtil.java */
public class ObjectUtil
{
    public static native NativeObject readNative(String path);
    public static native void writeNative(String path, NativeObject obj);
}
```

When I attempt to do ObjectUtil.readNative() in the beginning of my program, I get the following issues in logcat:

```
05-19 18:57:38.508: WARN/dalvikvm(365): No implementation found for native Lcom/navimatics/base/ObjectUtil;.readNative (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/navimatics/base/NativeObject;
05-19 18:59:15.409: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: readNative
```

My understanding is that because the class ObjectUtil references NativeObject, loading the ObjectUtil class should force the loading of the NativeObject class and thus the execution of the NativeObject static initializer which performs the System.LoadLibrary() call. It is not clear then why I would get the aforementioned logcat messages.

However if I modify ObjectUtil.java to read as follows there is no exception and the program works:

```
/* ObjectUtil.java */
public class ObjectUtil
{
    public static native NativeObject readNative(String path);
    public static native void writeNative(String path, NativeObject obj);
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("Base");
    }
}
```

It also works if I do this:

```
/* ObjectUtil.java */
public class ObjectUtil extends NativeObject
{
    public static native NativeObject readNative(String path);
    public static native void writeNative(String path, NativeObject obj);
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
The native side code that I was asked for is this:

```
static jobject JNICALL readNative(JNIEnv *env, jclass jcls, jstring jpath)
{
    // ...
}
static void JNICALL writeNative(JNIEnv *env, jclass jcls, jstring jpath, jobject jobj)
{
    // ...
}

static JNINativeMethod methods[] =
{
    { "readNative", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/navimatics/base/NativeObject;", readNative },
    { "writeNative", "(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/navimatics/base/NativeObject;)V", writeNative },
};
```

The methods are registered using JNIEnv.RegisterNatives().

Comment: You haven't provided the code of the native-side declarations, and the answer lies there

Comment: Code added as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You have two extra parenthesis in initializing the JNINativeMethod array, this code shouldn't compile.

Check the return code of RegisterNatives(), it should be zero on success.

Also in case you're compiling a C++ code, you should declare the native methods `extern "C"` to avoid getting them mangled.

Comment: Ognian, you are right about the parentheses. However the extra parentheses do not exist in the original code. The original code contains a number of macros that I expanded by hand, hence the problems you saw. Fixed now.

Comment: I disagree about the extern "C" observation however. Recall that RegisterNatives() registers function pointers. The names of these static functions are not relevant.

Comment: You're right about `extern "C"`. Did you check the return value of `RegisterNatives`, did they get successfully registered?

Comment: RegisterNatives() returns success **if** it gets called. As explained, if I explicitly call System.loadLibrary() and then ObjectUtil.readNative() it works without issues. The problem happens only when I call ObjectUtil.readNative() without having called System.loadLibrary() first. However this should not cause an issue, because ObjectUtil references the NativeObject class, which does call System.loadLibrary() in a static initializer. Please see my original post for a full explanation.